# How to do conditional compilation with TASM?

Tags: assembly, dos, conditional-compilation, tasm

I'd like how to pass arguments when compiling a TASM program in order to compile section of the code optionally, that would be the equivalent of #ifdef with the -D argument in C.
How can I do that with TASM ?

Comment: Did you read the User guide for TASM (page 11 for version TASM 5), you got with your Turbo Assembler, when you bought it? On page 15 there are even some examples of one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The /d option defines a symbol for your source file, exactly as if it
>   were defined on the first line of your file with the =directive. You
>   can use this option as many times as you wanf on the command line.

Thanks for the input @Ped7g

Comment: np. If you would use some free tools with available online documentation, I will even add answer with citation next time. :) But in the world of closed commercial SW I'm somewhat reluctant to do that... especially for an obsolete piece of SW, which I didn't bought (and my university license doesn't apply to me for more than a decade ... but made me familiar with TASM in those days .. a lot).

Comment: Quoting a snippet of documentation is obviously considered fair-use, @ped7g, especially if you give credit to the original source. And ethically speaking, Borland TASM is clearly abandon-ware at this point, so I see absolutely nothing wrong with making significant information about it available, or continuing to use your original license.